# Error connecing to remote PC to monitor running services

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query

Wrote this in C#. Second console program I've done. It compiles and runs. But when it gets to connecting to the client. It says the client doesn't exist. I am connecting to my local machine in the code by PC Name. Even when trying to connect to a remote machine I get the same message.

I removed the computer name, domain, and username but left text just as the info was entered.

Error is on line 50, foreach (CimInstance process in allProcesses)

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Management;
using System.Security;
using Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Options;



namespace WMITest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string computer = "MyPC";
        string domain = "MyDomain";
        string username = "MyUserName";

        string password;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Password:");
        password = Console.ReadLine();

        SecureString securepassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in password)
        {
            securepassword.AppendChar(c);
        }

        // Create Creds
        CimCredential Credentials = new CimCredential(PasswordAuthenticationMechanism.Default, 
                                                    domain,
                                                   username,
                                                   securepassword);

        // Create Session Options using Creds
        WSManSessionOptions sessionOptions = new WSManSessionOptions();
        sessionOptions.AddDestinationCredentials(Credentials);

        //create session using computer, sessionOptions
        CimSession Session = CimSession.Create(computer, sessionOptions);

        var allProcesses = Session.QueryInstances(@"root\cimv2", "WQL", "Select * from Win32_Service where name like '%MSSQL$%'");

// Connection Options
ConnectionOptions wmcon = new ConnectionOptions();
        ManagementScope wmscp = null;

        wmcon.Username = username;
        wmcon.Password = password;
        wmcon.Authority = "ntlmdomain:" + domain;

        wmscp = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + computer + "\\root\\CIMV2", wmcon);

        wmscp.Connect();

        // Loop Through instances
        foreach (CimInstance process in allProcesses) //<--- This line is where error is popping up
        {

            if (process.CimInstanceProperties["SQL Services"].ToString()[0] > ' ')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SQL server {0} is currently {1}",
                            process.CimInstanceProperties["Name"],
                            process.CimInstanceProperties["Status"]);
            }
        }Console.ReadLine();
    }   
}

}
```

Below is the error I get

> Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimException: 'The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig".'

I have confirmed the service is running on both my local and remote machine. I am at a loss.

Comment: So I found I wasn't opening the connection anywhere.

Comment: Added the following:
 // Connect to machine
             and now getting an access denied. Invalid username/password.

Now getting invalid username/password. Do I have 2 connections being attempted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after beating on this for a bit I decided to start over using WMI Code Creator from Microsoft (URL: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572). This essentially built everything I needed to connect remotely using a different account than I am logged in with.

Thank you to those who took time to look this over.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Management;
using System.Security;
using Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Options;



namespace WMITest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string computer;
        string domain = "";
        string username = "Administrator";

        string password;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter PC IP Address:");
        computer = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Password:");
        password = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();

        try
        {
            ConnectionOptions connection = new ConnectionOptions();
            connection.Username = username;
            connection.Password = password;
            connection.Authority = "ntlmdomain:" + domain;

            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(
                "\\\\" + computer + "\\root\\cimv2", connection);
            scope.Connect();

            ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE Name like 'MSSQL$%'");

            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Win32_Service instance");
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", queryObj["Name"]);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (ManagementException err)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + err.Message);
        }
        catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException unauthorizedErr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connection error (user name or password might be incorrect): " + unauthorizedErr.Message);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

["The error means you haven’t got the winrm service running on the local/remote machine. On modern Windows remoting, and therefore winrm, are enable by default for servers but disable for client OS e.g. Windows 10. Easiest way to get this to work is run 'Enable-PSremoting' from and elevated PowerShell prompt."](https://richardspowershellblog.wordpress.com/2016/11/04/computername-parameters-for-cim-and-wmi-cmdlets/)

[We should not be using WMI anymore because it is deprecated](https://richardspowershellblog.wordpress.com/2017/09/26/cim-not-wmi/)

Comment: I get the same error when running commands similar to the asker, for example,  `CimSession.Create("localhost").QueryInstances(@"root\CIMV2", "WQL", $"SELECT Version FROM Win32_OperatingSystem")`.  Isn't that CIM, not WMI?  I'm wondering if your warning about WMI being deprecated is relevant to the error, or if I'm misunderstanding something and am using a deprecated API that I should not be using.  It seems silly to have to enable remote access just to query simple properties like operating system version on the same machine as the running code.